# Trying to use Ruby in a Jquery selector, that is within an ERB file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In index.html.erb, I have:

```
<button type="submit" id="<%= Book.first.id %>">Activate</button>
```

further down the page, I have:

```
<script>
$("#<%= Book.first.id %>").click(function(event){
     // do something
    });
<script>
```

But when I try to render the page, I get error:

```
undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass
$("#<%= Book.first.id %>").click(function(event){
```

Am I getting this error because `<%= Book.first.id %>` hasn't rendered on the page yet? My knowledge of Jquery says I shouldn't even get that error until I attempt to click it.

I took a look at the (self-answered) answer here: [How use a ruby code inside the javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37284251/how-use-a-ruby-code-inside-the-javascript) and I think what I'm doing is possible.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a lot going on in this question.

Since you're getting an error from Rails.

Are you sure that Book.first exists? You can test this in a console.

Other observations:

1. You're missing a closing tag in this line before Activate

   `<button type="submit" id="<%= Book.first.id %>"(missing closing tag here)Activate</button>`
2. Don't do model calls in the view. This is what the controller/helpers are for... embrace [MVC](https://betterexplained.com/articles/intermediate-rails-understanding-models-views-and-controllers/)

   ```
   # in controller 
   @books = Book.all

   # in view
   <button type="submit" id="<%= @books.first.id %>">Activate</button>

   <script>
     $("#<%= @books.first.id %>").click(function(event){
     // do something
     });
   <script>
   ```
3. You're trying to execute JavaScript inline but on DOM elements. In JS land you have no guarantee it exists yet. IMO it's best not to use inline JavaScript if it can be avoided. So move this into your main Javascript files (asset pipeline). This type of function belongs in an onLoad block specifically so you can be sure it exists when you operate upon it. It's easier to wrap those in a erb tag too although see the next part for how to not even need to do that.
4. Instead of doing this the way you're trying via the HTML id tag you might want to embrace [data-attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) and [unobtrusive JavaScript](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html#unobtrusive-javascript). This would allow you to attach the onClick tag and parse out the data-attribute to get the ID verse having to know it ahead of time, i.e. interpolating with `<%= something %>`.

Comment: man I've been doing it wrong. This link: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html#unobtrusive-javascript is precisely what I need - and written for a numpty like me to understand.

Comment: :) As you learn be sure to check out the react-rails gem, https://github.com/reactjs/react-rails,  if you want JS front-end style of components with back-end rails. It's well written and lets you get up and running on react pretty quickly.

Answer (score 1):

You can use class and get attribute id

```
<button type="submit" class="submit-btn" id="<%= Book.first.id %>"> Activate </button>

<script>
  $(".submit-btn").click(function(event){
     console.log($(this).attr('id'))
  });
<script>
```